# How to get py2exe to build in copyright information

Tags: python, windows, exe, py2exe

I am using Py2exe to create a Windows .exe from my Python script.  I would like to have the copyright information as well as the product version, description, etc.  I've been able to get everything to show (in the Properties > Details of the exe), except for the copyright information.  I've tried the following with no success:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")
    sys.argv.append("-q")

class Target:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
        # for the versioninfo resources
        self.version = "1.0.0.0"
        self.company_name = "ACME."
        self.copyright = "Copyright (c) 2014 ACME."
        self.name = "My Program"

# create an instance of class Target
# and give it additional needed info
target = Target(
    description = "Test Description",
    # this is your code file
    script = "Main.py",
    # this will form TestProgram.exe
    dest_base = "TestProgram")

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1,
                          'compressed': 1}},
    console = [{'script': "Main.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

When using this method I get the File Description, Product Name, and Product version in the PROPERTIES > DETAILS of the .exe but I am missing the copyright.

Answer (score 6):

I got the following to work.  I realized I didn't set the target right.  Fixed at the bottom where I did `console = [target]`.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")
    sys.argv.append("-q")

class Target:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
        self.version = "1.0.0.0"
        self.company_name = "ACME."
        self.copyright = "Copyright (c) 2014 ACME."
        self.name = "My Program"

target = Target(
    description = "Test Description",
    script = "Main.py",
    dest_base = "TestProgram")

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1,
                          'compressed': True}},
    zipfile = None,
    console = [target]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

user2643864's answer is more complicated than it needs to be. jgritty's answer is nearly there, and only needs simple modification, adding a couple of entries in the dictionary assigned to `console`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1,
                          'compressed': 1}},
    console = [{
        'script': 'Main.py',
        'copyright': 'Copyright (C) 2016 ACME Pty Ltd',
        'company_name': 'ACME Pty Ltd',
    }],
    zipfile = None,
    version = '1.0.0.0',
    name = 'My Program',
    description = 'Test Description',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's something really wrong with your code, because it doesn't update the File Description, Product Name, and Product version in the exe.  However, this code does:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1,
                          'compressed': 1}},
    console = [{'script': "Main.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
    version = "1.0.0.0",
    name = "My Program",
    description = "Test Description",
)
```

To put the company name and copyright info into the executable is more challenging, and unfortunately, I don't know how to do that yet.  [This](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomDataInExe) might be useful.

Comment: Ya, there was something wrong with my code.  I figured it out and will post the answer.  I also tried what you supplied in your answer, but the copyright information would never display.  Only the description, name and version would display (even if copyright was specified).

Comment: I'm interested to see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for 2023. There is a new [freeze API](https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/blob/master/docs/py2exe.freeze.md) that is the new way to compile your code. I found it was the only reliable way I could get the copyright and product version to appear using Python 3.11+.

```
from py2exe import freeze
 
freeze(
   console = [myservice],
   zipfile = None,
   options = {'bundle_files': 3,'compressed': 1},
   version_info={
      'version':'1.0.0',
      'product_version':'03012023',
      'product_name':'My Service',
      'copyright':'Copyright 2023 My Company',
   }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mbokil. It's properly working for me.

**INFO:** py2exe is going to stop support on the setup API and recommending users to start using py2exe.freeze API to build standalone .exe file of your code.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34611872)